# Setup unit (jest) test shopware-docker shopware 6

Tags: node.js, docker, unit-testing, jestjs, shopware6

I try to setup the test environment for **unit (jest) testing** for my ***custom* plugin vue files** in Shopware6 using [shopware-docker](https://github.com/shyim/shopware-docker/)

The [provided documentation](https://github.com/shyim/shopware-docker/wiki/Commands) is, at least for me, not really helpful. following a list of unclear hints:

1. What means *Module: **base*** vs *Module: **classic*** vs *Module: **platform***? Which one i have installed? Where are a useful documentation about? The folder structure does not provide named modules

> Like when the target project is Shopware 5 Git installation, to include base + classic or on Shopware 6, base + platform.

I started with Shopware 6, so i confused about this nexus

2. Trying command `swdc admin-jest <project-name>` inside `Module: platform`, the only which appointed the administration, returns:

```
rammi@rammi-laptop-i7:~/Code/my-project$ swdc admin-jest my-project
Installing Node v12.22.12 (x64)
warning: Version already installed at "/nvm/.debian-fnm/node-versions/v12.22.12"
Using Node v12.22.12
Writing definition to file ...
Done!
Using Node for alias lts-gallium

> administration@1.0.0 unit-watch
> jest --config jest.config.js --watch
No tests found related to files changed since last commit.
Press `a` to run all tests, or run Jest with `--watchAll`.
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------

Watch Usage
 › Press a to run all tests.
 › Press f to run only failed tests.
 › Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 › Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 › Press q to quit watch mode.
 › Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

Thats all..., but i think, there must be a environment configuration to achieve tests, but i dont find nothing in the official documentations. Also using google without success.

What i found is the command `composer run admin:create:test` from [this documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/testing/jest-admin#setup-tests-with-create-test-command). But the command does not exist in `shopware-docker` repository. And a similar command is not available.

Summary: **How to setup jest for custom plugin using shopware-docker**?

**Edit #1**

I have already created a simple test like this

```
// custom/plugins/MyPlugin/src/Resources/app/administration/test/module/my-module/view/module-view.spec.js

describe('module-view', () => {
    it('should be false', () => {
        expect(false).toBeTruthy()
    })
})
```

Using the provided command `Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.` and putting `module-view` response with

```
Watch Usage: Press w to show more.

Active Filters: filename /module-view/

Pattern Mode Usage
 › Press Esc to exit pattern mode.
 › Press Enter to filter by a filenames regex pattern.

 pattern › module-view.spec.js
No tests found, exiting with code 0
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Comment: So essentially you are asking how to run Cypress tests for a custom module? Did you gather any more information in the meantime?

Comment: @Alex thx for answering, it is already done. IActually i use cypress like recommend by cypress itself (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/installing-cypress)

Comment: can you post the details as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

As i can't use the recommend way by shopware, this is my current solution:

- create folder `test/e2e` in `~/%my_plugin%/src/Resources/app/administration/`
- go to folder `e2e`
- run `npm install cypress --save-dev`
- run to start cypress `node_modules/.bin/cypress open`

BTW: the current solution cover e2e tests, but cypress [also offer solution for `component tests`](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/testing-types#What-is-Component-Testing), which can used for `unit test`